# operator << operloaded API for std::endl?

Tags: c++

I am really confused while overloading << operator as friend function.

```
This line works fine 
cout << endl;

But this line gives compilation issue. Why ??
operator <<(cout, endl);
```

Below is the sample code

```
  class Logger
{
    int _id;
    string _name;
  public:

  Logger(int id, string name):_id(id),_name(name){
      cout<<"Constructor"<<endl;
  }
  ~Logger(){
      cout<<"destructor"<<endl;
  }
  friend ostream& operator <<( ostream& out,Logger& log);

};

ostream& operator << (ostream& out,Logger& log)
{
      out<<log._id<<" "<<log._name;
      return out;
}
```

And What is the need of return statment ? Without return also the below statment works fine.

cout<< log << endl << endl << log2 << endl << log3 << endl;

Comment: What do you {want|expect} the second line to do?

Comment: I don't see `operator<<(cout, endl)` anywhere in your sample code.

Comment: Also, lookup what happens when you don't return from a function that returns not-void

Comment: @Beta I was expecting the second line shouldn't give compilation issue. I know std::endl is not object of Logger then how come first line works .

Comment: "But this line gives compilation issue." -- what is the issue that it gives? Is there an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: @rustyx -- when `operator<<` is a free function you can call it as a function: `operator<<(std::cout, std::string("abcd"));`.

Comment: @PeteBecker it gives the following error: no matching function for call to ‘operator<<(std::ostream&, )’

Answer (score 1):

The `operator<<` that takes a stream manipulator is a member function of `basic_ostream`. You can't call it as if it were a free function; you have to call it as a member function:

```
std::cout.operator<<(std::endl)
```

On the other hand, the stream inserter that takes a `std::string` is a free function, and you can call it with the usual function call:

```
std::string text = "Hello, world";
operator<<(std::cout, text);
```

but not as a member function.

`std::endl` is usually the wrong thing to use; `'\n'` ends a line, without the extra stuff that `std::endl` does.